# how to reference branch in gitlab markdown?

Tags: git, gitlab, markdown

I would like to use gitlab markdown syntax to refer to a branch in README.md file.
I tried `@develop`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "reference a branch" ? You mean reference a file or a directory of a specific branch ?

Comment: I don't see branch references in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#special-gitlab-references

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I can open a html page with the branch. It has a specific URL, which is globally accessible. I want to be able to access this, even when branch is renamed, or when URL changes.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what you were looking for but at least something - try this markdown construct.

```
[myReference](../../tree/myBranch/myPath/myFile.cpp#L310-313)
```

This will navigate you away from the main branch towards the branch you want (myBranch in this example)

However if the branchname changes then things will be broken. I really feel this functionality should be added to gitlab in near future

Comment: You are not alone: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27508

Comment: Issue mentionned by @HaraldErnst moved to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17084